# how to write the regex for these special character..?

Tags: javascript, regex

how to write the regex for these special character that is (abc123),[abc123],%, &,-, _ COMMA and DOT.

```
Example:-

abc --> allow
ABC --> allow
123 --> allow
% --> allow
-  --> allow
_  --> allow
&   --> allow
. (dot) --> allow
, (comma)  --> allow

these characters only wants to allow athor than not allowed..
```

I have tried code here..

```js
textarea: {
  validators: {
    notEmpty: {
      message: 'This field is required and cannot be empty'
    },
    stringLength: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200,
      message: 'Your text must be more than 0 and less than 200 characters only'
    },
    regexp: {
      regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9%\s()&]+$/,
      message: 'Your text can consist of alphabetical, number,space and %(percentage), [,],(,),&,-,_ COMMA, and DOT only'

    }
  }

},
```

Comment: Add the missing characters in your characters class ? Note that the hyphen `-` must either be at the end, or be escaped

Comment: regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9%\s()&_.,-]+$/       is this right?

Comment: This seems right. Did you try it ? Note that `\s` will allow white spaces too

Comment: white space also i want to allow sir.. thank you so much...